# Htmlpurifier IMG SRC purify

Tags: validation, sanitization, htmlpurifier

i have problem with Htmlpurifier settings. If my input is for example (its URL for logging out):

```
<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8888/app/public/user/login/logout">
```

Htmlpurifier is not able to purify this input. Only add "ALT" but the code is processed and user is logged out. Is any possibility to handle this?

My htmlpurifier settings is:

```
require_once('htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php');
    $config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
    $config->set('Core.Encoding', 'UTF-8');
    $config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'HTML 4.01 Transitional');
    $config->set('Core.RemoveInvalidImg',true);
    $purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

$clean = $purifier->purify($dirty);
```

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-posted here: http://htmlpurifier.org/phorum/read.php?3,6194